# How to do CSS wild card search?

Tags: css

I have three `divs` with following class:

```
<div class="page-search-site health-bundle-medical-group">Some text here</div>
<div class="health-bundle-clinic">Some text here 2</div>
<div class="page-search-site health-bundle-hospital">Some text here 3</div>
```

Here `health-bundle-` text is common for all three classes. So I want to write a CSS which will work for all these three classes, which will work if it matches the common part. Is it possible?

Comment: You mean `page-search-site-health-bundle page-search-site-health-bundle-medical-group` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called attribute selector. An example, using your html structure, is the following:

```
div.page-search-site[class*='-bundle-medical-group']  {
    color:red 
}
```

In the place of `div` you can add any element or remove it altogether, and in the place of `class` you can add any attribute of the specified element.

```
div.page-search-site[class*='-bundle-medical-group']
div.page-search-site[class*='-bundle-hospital']
div.page-search-site[class*='-bundle-clinic']
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/sajib_hassan/jku1fdh8/

More information on CSS attribute selectors, you can find [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector) and [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors).

Comment: Thanks for your answer with details. It worked!!

Comment: Is this not the complete reverse of what you were looking for, which was to be able to select the elements based on the text their class names have in common?

Answer (score 1):

```css
div[class|=page-search-site-health-bundle] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-search-site-health-bundle-medical-group">Some text here</div>
<div class="page-search-site-health-bundle-clinic">Some text here</div>
<div class="page-search-site-health-bundle-hospital">Some text here</div>
```

Read More (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a selctor that selects all elements with a list of class names beginning with `health-bundle-` or containing `health-bundle-` preceded by a space so you'll need to use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), rather than [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors), which don't support wildcards.

```css
[class^="health-bundle-"],[class*=" health-bundle-"]{
    color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-search-site health-bundle-medical-group">Some text here</div>
<div class="health-bundle-clinic">Some text here 2</div>
<div class="page-search-site health-bundle-hospital">Some text here 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="page-search-site-health-bundle type-medical-group">Some text here</div>
<div class="page-search-site-health-bundle type-clinic">Some text here</div>
<div class="page-search-site-health-bundle type-hospital">Some text here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div[class*="health-bundle"]{background:red;}
```

Comment: Note that this won't select the second element, which doesn't have a `.page-search-site` class.

Comment: use div[class*="health-bundle"]{background:red;} you changed html code

Comment: Is there anything common in your class you can use [class*="common word"]

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector you're looking for looks like this.

```css
div.page-search-site[class*=health-bundle]
```

It selects all `div` elements with class `page-search-site` and class attribute containing the substring `health-bundle`.

Comment: I take it you didn't test this before posting it? It won't match *any* of the elements included in the question.

Comment: Ah, I see your point.  I didn't think about the fact that the class attribute has all the classes so it would never work.  Blame my laziness, but I'll fix this tomorrow; it's pretty late here.